# Django model trouble

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

**Hello everyone**, maybe someone has encountered such a problem.
I'm trying to create a UserProfile model using a One-To-one relationship with the User table from django.contrib.auth.models.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

But when I create a migration with `manage.py makemigrations`, the user field does not exist

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True
    dependencies = [
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Profile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('age', models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('status', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('avatar', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'User Profile',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'User Profile',
                'ordering': ['-created_at'],
            },
        ),
    ]
```

what am I doing wrong?)

**django version 3.2.5**
**Postgre 13**

*thank you in advance)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `User` model as well.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OnetoOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

You also need to point the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to this `User` model.

```py
# settings.py
settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<user_app_name>/models.py'
```

You may consult the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) to read in detail.